# 2 Lines Causing thousands of Java Script Errors

Tags: javascript, header, sticky

On this page: https://www.airsyspro.com There is a script for a stick header that seems to have an infinite loop that is causing thousands of errors in the console.  Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

You'll see in the console that it appears on lines 2216 and 2245. JS is not my expertise, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it all starts with the $('.hpg-sticky-bar');   It can't find an element with that class. Therefore the 'original' class will never get added to the element. The function stickIt()  want to get the top value of a element with the class 'original' as a result the error.  Because of the 'scrollIntervalID' every 10ms, you will get the error many times.
Solution wrap this script in a check like    if ($('.hpg-sticky-bar').length) {}

Comment: Thanks for the response.  on line 358 there is a class named .hpg-sticky-bar is it not seeing it. Do you know why?

Comment: An element with this class is not present in the source code. Try in the console for example jQuery('.hpg-sticky-bar').length;   It returns 0

Comment: That's a good point.  Check out this page: https://www.airsyspro.com/products/ The element does exist there and it looks like the error is still triggering

Comment: Sorry I still don't see an element that has a class="hpg-sticky-bar"  in the source code. Also on this products page. If you want the errors to stop, wrap the script in a   if ($('.hpg-sticky-bar').length)   statement :)

Comment: Any way you'd be willing to show me how that would be applied to the code? I'm sorry for asking I'm very new to JS

Comment: I've added the code as an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($('.hpg-sticky-bar').length) {
    $('.hpg-sticky-bar').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.hpg-sticky-bar').addClass('cloned').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('margin-top','0').css('z-index','500').removeClass('original').hide();
    
    scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);
    
    
    function stickIt() {
    
      var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
      orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;               
    
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {
        // scrolled past the original position; now only show the cloned, sticky element.
    
        // Cloned element should always have same left position and width as original element.     
        orgElement = $('.original');
        coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
        leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;  
        widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');
        $('.cloned').css('left',leftOrgElement+'px').css('top',0).css('width',widthOrgElement).show();
        $('.original').css('visibility','hidden');
      } else {
        // not scrolled past the menu; only show the original menu.
        $('.cloned').hide();
        $('.original').css('visibility','visible');
      }
    }
}
```

It can be as simple as the example here above

Comment: Thank you for your expertise.  You are a true professional.  I can't express how much I appreciate you taking time out of your day to help me.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is this:

```js
  var orgElementPos = $('.original1').offset();
```

There is not a single element with class 'original'.
The var `orgElementPos` is null.

Also check this:

```js
$('.msb-sticky-bar').addClass('original1')
```

the class `msb-sticky-bar` is misssing.

Comment: on line 2208 there is .addClass('original') The sticky header works so I believe that class exists. Anything else you'd suggest. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you check the current page? That class `msb-sticky-bar` is missing! Can you check that the code in 2208 is executed? Can you check if `orgElementPos` is null?